# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`…`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"

Tags: python, numpy, data-science, forecasting

I am trying to implement 3 months simple moving average as a forecast for a  demand series(d) using a function & I get following error !

def moving_avg(d,extra_periods=1,n=3):

```
    # transfer the input in to numpy array 
    d=np.array(d)

    # historical period length 
    cols=len(d)

    # append np.nan in to the demand array to cover future period 
    d=np.append(d[np.nan]*extra_periods)

    # Define the forecast array 
    f= np.full(cols+extra_periods,np.nan)

    # create all the t+1 forecast untill end of historical period 
    for t in range (n,cols+1):
        f[t]=np.mean(d[t-n:t])

        # forecast for all extra periods 
        f[cols+1:]=f[t]

    # Return the dataframe with demand , forecast and error 

    df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Demand":d,"Forecast":f,"Error":d-f})
    return df
d=[37,60,85,112,132,145,179,198,212,232]
df=moving_avg(d,extra_periods=1,n=3)
```

IndexError: only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Can you detail what you want to do and the purpose of this function ?

Comment: Its for simple moving average of 3 periods

Comment: What have you done to narrow down the problem?

Comment: e.g- d=[37,60,85,112,132,145,179,198,212,232]                                 
d=np.array(d)
d=np.append(d[np.nan])  getting the subject error !